# Python Logic to find the sum of a sub list satisfying a condition

Tags: python, list

I need to find the sum of the list elements between `-1` and `-1`.

I tried this solution,but it adds the elements `1,2,3` to `1,1,1,1` .Can you help me with a better logic ?

```
lis = [1,2,3,4,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,2,3]
sum = 0
newlis = []
    for i in range(0,len(lis)-1):
        if lis[i] == -1:
            while i+1 < len(lis) and lis[i+1]!=-1:
                sum = sum+lis[i+1]
                i = i+1
print(sum)
```

Comment: What's the expected output?

Comment: This isn't a question you can properly answer. This site is not for asking your homework questions.

Comment: Would there be exactly 2 -1s in every case?

Comment: @MT756 , -1 is there in index 4 and and index 9

Comment: Your question only has one -1, so I was confused. Didn't pay attention to the list in the code.

Comment: @Ch3steR the expected output is 4 [ adding 1,1,1,1 between the two -1's]

Comment: @MT756 ...got it...my bad...its already corrected

Comment: Will there be more than two -1s?

Comment: @IsaíHinojos Actually people can ask homework questions, as long as they are asking it the right way. [how do I ask and answer homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions#:~:text=1%20Answer&text=This%20is%20an%20attempt%20to,close%20all%20homework%20questions%20immediately.)

Comment: Are you interested in only one such sub list or multuple sublists?

Comment: What would be the output if `lis = [1,2,3,4,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,2,3,-1]` now??

Answer (score 3):

You can use:

```
idx = [i for i, v in enumerate(lis, 1) if v == -1]
print(sum(lis[idx[0]:idx[1]-1]))
# 4
```

[Demo](https://trinket.io/python3/bf5a89b276)

Comment: Likely the most efficient answer here. Great use of enumerate!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example that works without `lambda`

```py
lis = [1,2,3,4,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,2,3]

first = lis.index(-1) + 1
second = lis[first:].index(-1) + first

result = sum(lis[first:second])
```

Comment: There are probably 10 more efficient ways of doing this. The original Lambda answer, for instance, is far better. This is just an alternative solution that's easier to read for new Pythonistas.

Answer (score 1):

We can first compute the indexes where -1 appears:

```
In [12]: l = [1,2,3,4,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,2,3]
In [16]: indexes = [index for index in range(len(l)) if l[index] == -1]
In [17]: indexes
Out[17]: [4, 9]
```

Now, we know that -1 appears at indexes 4 & 9. To verify that we have the right set of numbers:

```
In [20]: l[indexes[0]:indexes[1]]
Out[20]: [-1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

So, computing the sum is easier now:

```
In [19]: sum(l[indexes[0]:indexes[1]])
Out[19]: 3
```

Comment: Actually I just edited the questions , l = l = [1,2,3,4,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,2,3] ...watch for the two -1s. ....How would you suggest to edit the lost comprension for this list ?

Comment: print(sum([i for i in l[1:] if i == 1]))
 works....Thanks for the hint

Comment: the list comprehension is also looking for -1, so it will be taken care. With the list you just provided, I get answer as 2.

Comment: This `[i for i in l[1:] if i==-1 or i==1]` is wrong. Because question obviously said that element should be between -1 and 1, which means `lis` may be 0 or something. And you omitted first element of array by indexing `l[1:]`.

Comment: @vijayananth, can you confirm if you want something like what F.Nix mentioned in previous comment?

Answer (score 1):

One approach is that you could create a boolean flag which sets to true when you see a -1 and set it back to false when you see the second -1 (or break). You add the numbers if the flag is true.

```
lis = [1,2,3,4,-1,1,1,1,1,-1,1,2,3]
sum = 0
flag = False;
for i in range(len(lis)):
    if not flag:
        if lis[i] == -1:
            flag = True
    elif lis[i] == -1:
        flag = False #this line could be omitted
        break
    else:
        sum += lis[i]
print(sum)
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you mean this?

```
sum(filter(lambda n: -1 <= n <= 1, lis))
```

or without lambda:

```
def f(n):
  return -1 <= n <= 1

sum(filter(f, lis))
```

Comment: Yeah..This works...can you help me understand this logic

Comment: Also would appreciate a logic without using lambda

Comment: Of course. Which part you didn't understand exactly

Comment: I edited the answer to give you the version without lambda too.

Comment: In python built-ins `filter` gets iters like a list and a boolean function in order to return a new iter that contains only items you permitted with your condition, in this case number should be between -1 and 1. Then simply add iter items together with `sum` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lis.index` to find the first -1. It also offers a second parameter for where to start the search, so you can also use it to find the second -1. Then just get the slice between them and sum it.

```
>>> start = lis.index(-1) + 1
>>> stop = lis.index(-1, start)
>>> sum(lis[start:stop])
4
```